# How can I do an Combined UPDATE statement and Multiple Different Condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-update, updates

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and trying to use SQL to update table at once with one query:
Query  has Different Where Condition and Sub query.
I have Tried Case when Condition but not able to get desire result

```
Update TPort
 set DRecd = 
((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.SchemeCode and
(CASE WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) and SCCode not in (3360,2059,291,288,2041,4003,5429,3724) THEN 1  
     WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) and SCCode  in (4003,5429,3724) THEN 1 
     WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND  SCCode in (3360) THEN 1 
     WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (2059,291,288,2041) THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
    END )=1
and Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
) * UNITS) 
Where TType like 'Reinvestment%' and IType = '3'
```

Here is 4 Query:

```
 Update TPort
     set DRecd = 
    ((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
    Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.Scode and Divd.[RecordDate] > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101)
    and Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
    ) * UNITS) 
    Where TType like 'RInvest%' and IType = '3' and SCCode not in (3360,2059,291,288,2041,4003,5429,3724)


Update TPort set DRecd = ((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.Scode and Divd.[RecordDate] >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101)
and Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
) * UNITS) 
Where TType like 'RInvest%' and IType = '3' and SCCode  in (4003,5429,3724)


Update TPort set DRecd = ((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.Scode and Divd.EXDIVDATE >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101)
and Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
) * UNITS) 
Where TType like 'RInvest%' and IType = '3'  and SCCode in (3360)


Update TPort set DRecd = ((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.Scode and Divd.EXDIVDATE > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101)
and Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
) * UNITS) 
Where TType like 'RInvest%' and IType = '3'  and SCCode in (2059,291,288,2041)
```

But Problem is it's taking sum of Rsrate should be Different for each where for subquery?If you check All Four Query all are same except there SCcode and 
subquery condition .  I hope that makes it clearer.

How can I do this in MS SQL Server?
Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can't see how correlated subqueries are different in 4 updates. Effectively this 4 updates update entire table excluding nulls in `TType` , `IType`, `SCCode` with a value totally depending on the current updated raw only.

Comment: Subquery Fetch Sum of  Rsrate for Every Scode with Respective their TR_date but Only Condition changes was inside table EXDIVDATE (>,>=) and RecordDate(>,>=) and Updating table SCCode

Comment: As written in the OP subquery filters `TDiv` only by `Scode` of the current `TPort` raw being updated . Provide sample input data and desired result to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Got Answer With Little Correction of Above Answer

```
UPDATE TPort 
SET DRecd =
((select IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) from TDiv Divd 
Where TPort.SCCode = Divd.SchemeCode 
AND (CASE WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] > convert(varchar, TPort .TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode not in (3360,2059,291,288,2041,4003,5429,3724) THEN 1  
          WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] >= convert(varchar, TPort .TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode  in (4003,5429,3724) THEN 1 
          WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE >= convert(varchar, TPort .TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (3360) THEN 1 
          WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE > convert(varchar, TPort .TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (2059,291,288,2041) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) = 1
and SCH_CODE = SCCode 
) * UNITS) 
Where Tran_Type in ('Reinvestment','ReinvestmentAm','ReInvestmentTI') and IType = '3' and SCH_CODE = OSch_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below syntax for your update query -

```
Update TP
SET DRecd = IsNull(Sum(RSrate), 0) * UNITS
FROM TPort TP
JOIN TDiv Divd ON TP.SCCode = Divd.SchemeCode
AND (CASE WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode not in (3360,2059,291,288,2041,4003,5429,3724) THEN 1  
          WHEN Divd.[RecordDate] >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (4003,5429,3724) THEN 1 
          WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE >= convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (3360) THEN 1 
          WHEN Divd.EXDIVDATE > convert(varchar, TPort.TR_DATE, 101) AND SCCode in (2059,291,288,2041) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) = 1
AND Divd.[RecordDate] < CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
WHERE TType like 'Reinvestment%' and IType = '3'
```